# Apply attributes from one NSAttributedString to another

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

Browsing *Attributed String Programming Guide* and the documentation for `NSAttributedString` and `NSMutableAttributedString`, I can't see a straightforward way to take all the attributes from one string and apply them to another.

The only possibility I've found so far is to to use `-[NSAttributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:]` but that seems like a very long way around.

Am I missing something? Surely there must be a cleaner solution?

What I'm ultimately aiming to achieve is to take an attributed string from a static label I've configured in a Storyboard, change it to contain dynamic info and apply certain attributes over certain ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `- (NSDictionary *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)aRange` to get the attributes at a specific index (e.g. 0 for the first character in string). Then use this attribute in `- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes range:(NSRange)aRange` to set this attributes for all characters in range.